# Embedding classical information into norm of a quantum state

Tags: quantum-state, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

According to [An introduction to quantum machine learning (Schuld, Sinayskiy & Petruccione, 2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3097), Seth Lloyd et al. say in their paper: [Quantum algorithms for supervised and unsupervised machine learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0411) that classical information can be encoded into the norm of a quantum state $\langle x|x \rangle = |\vec{x}|^{-1}\vec{x}$. I'm not sure I understand their notation.

Let's take a simple example. Say I want to store this array: $V = \{3,2,1,2,3,3,5,4\}$ of size $2^{3}$ in the state of an $3$-qubit quantum  system.

I can represent the state of an $3$-qubit system as:

$|\psi\rangle = a_1|000\rangle + a_2|001\rangle + a_3|010\rangle + a_4|011\rangle + a_5|100\rangle + a_6|101\rangle + a_7|110\rangle + a_8|111\rangle$ (using standard basis) where $a_i\in \Bbb C \ \forall \ 1 \leq i\leq 8$.

I could represent $V$ as a vector $\vec{V} = 3 \hat{x}_1 + 2 \hat{x}_2 +... + 4 \hat{x}_8$ where $\{\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,...,\hat{x}_8\}$ forms an orthonormal basis in $\Bbb R^{8}$, and write the standard Euclidean norm for it as $|\vec{V}|=\sqrt{3^2+2^2+...+4^2}$.

After this, I'm confused as to how I'd get the coefficients $a_1,a_2,..,a_8$. Should I just assign $3$ to $a_1$, $2$ to $a_2$ and so on?

***But, then again***:

> Consider the vector $N=2^{n}$ dimensional complex vector $\vec{v}$
>   with components $\{v_i=|v_i|e^{i\phi_i}\}$. Assume that
>   $\{|v_i|,\phi_i\}$ are stored as floating point numbers in quantum
>   random access memory. Constructing the $\log_2 N$ qubit quantum state
>   $|v\rangle = |\vec{v}|^{-1/2}\vec{v}$ then takes $\mathcal{O}(\log_2
>  N)$ steps as long as the sub-norms are also given in the qRAM in which
>   case any state can be constructed in $\mathcal{O}(\log N)$ steps.

**Firstly**, I don't understand their notion of a $2^n$ dimensional *complex* vector. If each of the components of their classical data array has two floating point numbers, wouldn't encoding that into a $n$-qubit quantum state be equivalent to storing a $2\times 2^{n}$ size classical array in a $n$-qubit system? Yes, I do know that $a_1,a_2,..,a_{2^n}$ are complex numbers having both magnitude and direction, and hence can store $2\times 2^{n}$ amount of classical information. But they don't mention anywhere how they will convert classical data (say in form of a $2\times 2^{n}$ array) into that form. Moreover, there seems to be a restriction that phase of a complex number $a_i$ can only range from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$.

**Secondly**, let us assume that the initial data array we wanted to store in our quantum system was actually $V=\{\{3,\phi_1\},\{2,\phi_2\},...,\{4,\phi_8\}\}$.

If they define $|v\rangle$ as $|\vec{v}|^{-1/2}\vec{v}$ then $|V\rangle$ in our example would look something like $(\sqrt{3^2+2^2+...+4^2})^{-1/2}(|3e^{i\phi_1}||000\rangle + |2e^{i\phi_2}||001\rangle + ... + |4e^{i\phi_8}||111\rangle)$. But then we're losing all the information about the phases $\phi_i$, isn't it? So what was the use of starting with a *complex* vector (having both a phase and magnitude) in the first place, when we're losing that information when converting to $|V\rangle$ anyway? Or are we writing supposed to consider $|V\rangle$ as $(\sqrt{3^2+2^2+...+4^2})^{-1/2}(3e^{i\phi_1}|000\rangle + 2e^{i\phi_2}|001\rangle + ... + 4e^{i\phi_8}|111\rangle)$?

It would be really helpful if someone could explain where I am going wrong using some concrete examples regarding storage of classical data in an $n$-qubit system.

Comment: The Schuld *et al.* paper was written  quite early in the age of "quantum machine learning", and I have never had a deep enough interest in quantum machine machine learning (yet) to spend too much time learning it. So I won't try to to answer the question, but one  thing I can contribute is to answer your confusion about the *restriction* for the complex phase to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. This range of $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is actually not a "restriction" because it covers all possible mathematical phases that can ever exist. $-\pi$ to $\pi$ means -180 to 180 degrees, which is a full circle.

Comment: Anything beyond the range of $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is like saying 370 degrees, which is a complete circle plus another 10 degrees. So 370 degrees is equivalent to 10 degrees, and likewise for anything outside the range of $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand their notion of a $2^n$ dimensional *complex*
>   vector. If each of the components of their classical data array has
>   two floating point numbers, wouldn't encoding that into a $n$-qubit
>   quantum state be equivalent to storing a $2\times 2^{n}$ size
>   classical array in a $n$-qubit system?

You are absolutely correct that a $2\times 2^n$ classical array of nubers is stored in an n-qubit system.

But they are absolutely right that the vector's dimension is $2^n$. This is because the vector has $2^n$ rows, where each entry has 2 classical numbers.

You can also store the same vector in a $2\times 2^n$ array: $2^n$ rows are filled in with the real parts and $2^n$ rows by the imaginary parts, but this vector would ***not evolve according to the Schrödinger equation***.

I hope this helps resolve this part of the question.

> But they don't mention anywhere how they will convert classical data (say in form of a $2\times 2^{n}$ array) into that form.

You are right. **Just as Peter Shor never mentioned anywhere how his qubits for factoring will be prepared.**

This is up to the experimentalists, and it is *implementation-dependent*. This means that for NMR qubits you'd convert the classical data into qubits differently from superconducting qubits, or ion-trap qubits, or  quantum dot qubits, etc. Therefore I do not blame Shor, or any of the 6 authors of the 2 papers you mentioned (who are all theorists by the way), for not explaining how the qubits will be prepared.

> let us assume that the initial data array we wanted to store in our quantum system was actually $V=\{\{3,\phi_1\},\{2,\phi_2\},...,\{4,\phi_8\}\}$. If they define $|v\rangle$ as $|\vec{v}|^{-1/2}\vec{v}$ then $|V\rangle$ in our example would look something like $(\sqrt{3^2+2^2+...+4^2})^{-1/2}(|3e^{i\phi_1}||000\rangle + |2e^{i\phi_2}||001\rangle + ... + |4e^{i\phi_8}||111\rangle)$. But
>   then we're losing all the information about the phases $\phi_i$, isn't
>   it? So what was the use of starting with a *complex* vector (having
>   both a phase and magnitude) in the first place, when we're losing that
>   information when converting to $|V\rangle$ anyway?

You had it earlier in your question! "Consider the vector $N=2^{n}$ dimensional complex vector $\vec{v}$ with components $\{v_i=|v_i|e^{i\phi_i}\}$." Therefore the vector is:

\begin{equation}
|\vec{v}|^{-1/2}
\begin{pmatrix}|v_{1}|e^{i\phi_{1}}\\
|v_{2}|e^{i\phi_{2}}\\
\vdots\\
|v_{2^{n}}|e^{i\phi_{2^{n}}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Notice:
1) There's $2^n$ entries, not $2 \times 2^n$ 
2) There is NO norm around the phases, so this is why you have lost all information about the phases, because you put extra norm symbols where they shouldn't be :)

> Or are we writing supposed to consider $|V\rangle$ as
>   $(\sqrt{3^2+2^2+...+4^2})^{-1/2}(3e^{i\phi_1}|000\rangle +
>  2e^{i\phi_2}|001\rangle + ... + 4e^{i\phi_8}|111\rangle)$?

Closer! The correct answer is the vector I wrote above, which can be written like this:

$|\vec{v}|^{-1/2}\left( e^{i \phi_1} |00 \cdots 00\rangle + e^{i \phi_2} |00 \cdots 01\rangle + \cdots + e^{i \phi_{N}} |1\cdots 1\rangle\right)$.

***For your specific example***:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{3e^{i\phi_1}|000\rangle + 2e^{i\phi_8}|001\rangle + \cdots + 4e^{i\phi_8}|111\rangle}{\sqrt{77}}
\end{equation}

**The purpose of all of this is so that the sum of the squares of the coefficients is 1, which in my equation is true because the numberator is:**

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 3^2 + 5 ^2+ 4^2} = \sqrt{77}
\end{equation}

I hope that clears it up!

Comment: Umm, but $|V\rangle = |\vec{V}|^{-1/2}\vec{V}$ isn't it? Where is the $|\vec{V}|^{-1/2}$ in your expression?

Comment: But $|\vec{V}| = \begin{equation}
\sqrt{3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 3^2 + 5 ^2+ 4^2} = \sqrt{77}
\end{equation}$. So, $|\vec{V}|^{-1/2} = 77^{-1/4}$, no? Or are they using a different definition of norm?

Comment: All fixed now. There is a typo in the original Seth Lloyd paper. $\{v_i=|v_i|e^{i\phi_i}\}$ is not normalized. It should be divided by the norm of the vector. The $|\vec{v}|^{-1/2}|$ is called "normalization" by the way.

Comment: I ask because for a vector like $2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}+5\hat{k}$ the standard norm is $\sqrt{2^2+3^2+5^2}$

Comment: You are right I fixed that, is there still any problem?
I would appreciate if you accept the answer since this took way longer to type out than I originally thought.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78143/discussion-between-blue-and-user1271772).